# Rescaling and resizing embeded wmv file in webpage

Tags: html, embedding, wmv

i am embedding a wmv file in my webpage

but the problem is that i cant rescale the video frame to the object size and div

here's my code

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 220px;">
               <object width="300" height="220" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsm p2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112"> 
<param name="fileName" value="<?php echo base_url().$row['video_image'];?>"> 
<param name="autoStart" value="false"> 
<param name="showControls" value="true"> 
<param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="true"> 
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="ClickToPlay" value="true"> 
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
       WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="220" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="<?php echo base_url().$row['video_image'];?>" autoStart="false" ></embed>
</object>
               </div>
```

the problem with my above script is that if the video frame size is 700x500 then its not getting automatically resized to the object size or the div size like width=300px and height=220px

as such, some portion of the video cant be seen in the frame... i searched for a suitable answer, but cudnt find any...

```
EDIT
```

i used this following script as i got hint

```
<object classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
type="application/x-oleobject" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
<param name="URL" value="<?php echo base_url().$row['video_image'];?>" />
<param name="stretchToFit" value="1" />
<param name="showControls" value="1" />
<param name="showStatusBar" value="0" />
<param name="animationAtStart" value="1" />
<param name="autoStart" value="1" />
<param name="enableFullScreenControls" value="1"
/><embed src="<?php echo base_url().$row['video_image'];?>" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" autoStart="1" animationAtStart="1" enableFullScreenControls="1" stretchToFit="1" type="application/x-ms-wmp"/></embed></object>
```

though i have edited this script, still no effect is taking place

i saw that i can stretch the video frame size, but if i want to shrink the video-frame, that is not happening.. i mean if my video size is 300x200, then if i set the video size as 400x300, the the size is stretching..

but if i want to set the size as 100x80, the the video is running and only a protion of the video is being shown, as such it seems the video frame size is not getting shrinked

problem is that if in the second above code i delete the following line

```
<embed src="<?php echo base_url().$row['video_image'];?>" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" autoStart="1" animationAtStart="1" enableFullScreenControls="1" stretchToFit="1" type="application/x-ms-wmp"/></embed>
```

then also the video is playing in the google-chrome...but not in firefiox

so that means

```
<embed src="<?php echo base_url().$row['video_image'];?>" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" autoStart="1" animationAtStart="1" enableFullScreenControls="1" stretchToFit="1" type="application/x-ms-wmp"/></embed>
```

is responcible for the video in firefox.. now as i told earlier i can stretch the video frame  to bigger dimension, but cant shrink it to smaller dimension

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a 'StretchToFit' parameter (as a param and as an attribute on the embed element) and set its value to 'true'.

Note: This will not preserve the video's original aspect ratio.